# Webpage Forwading to domain

Tags: html, css, web, dns

I created a Website Containing *Home About Services and Contact us* . I created this in Dreamweaver.
but after this i want to buy a Domain name. i don't know how to Connect this! any Help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you say forwarding is not made the best sense to do it, You can upload all the files to your live server, where you will buy the hosting service. (If you don't know how to do this, I can help you about this)

Comment: Im New about this ! i need your help if youre not busy then